# Definition of equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, arzela-ascoli

In the literature I find several definitions for (uniform) equicontinuity of a family $M\in C[0,1]$. $M$ is called (uniformly) equicontinuous if ...

(1) $\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $|x(t)-x(s)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in M$ and $t,s \in[0,1]$ with $|t-s|<\delta$.

(2) $\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $\sup_{x\in M}|x(t)-x(s)|<\varepsilon$ for all $t,s \in[0,1]$ with $|t-s|<\delta$.

(3) $\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $\sup_{x\in M}\sup_{t,s\in [0,1], |t-s|<\delta}|x(t)-x(s)|<\varepsilon$.

(4) $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\sup_{x\in M}\sup_{t,s\in [0,1], |t-s|<\delta}|x(t)-x(s)|=0$.

Are these definitions all equivalent?

Comment: Yes they are equivalent. Have you tried proving it?

Comment: For a subset $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ it holds that $a<\varepsilon$ for all $a\in A$ $\Rightarrow$  $\sup A \le \varepsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $a\le \varepsilon$ for all $a\in A$. To handle the difference between $\le$ and $<$ use the $\le$-condition for $\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: Indeed, to add to @Jochen's comment, in (2), for example, you might have that the suprememum of $|x(t)-x(s)|$ is actually equal to $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The property mentioned by Jochen makes clear that definitions (1), (2) and (3) are equal. How can I prove that (4) is equivalent? And one more question: Can I change the supremum in (3), i.e. write $\sup_{|t-s|<\delta}\sup_{x\in m}|x(t)-x(s)|$?